# Does Npgsql block when calling NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() and a concurrent database update occurs in isolation level "Read Committed"?

Tags: c#, postgresql, transactions, npgsql, isolation-level

I would like to implement optimistic concurrency in my application code by means of a "revision" colum. I have C# code similar to this snippet:

```cs
public static async Task UpdateModelState(string connectionString, int id, int revision, string magicValue)
{
    var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    await using var transaction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

    await using var updateCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(
        "UPDATE foo_records SET revision = (@revision+1), magic_value = @magic_value"
        + " WHERE id = @id AND revision = @revision;",
        connection, transaction);
    updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("id", id));
    updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("revision", revision));
    updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("magic_value", magicValue));
    int numAffectedRows = await updateCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); // LINE A
    if (numAffectedRows == 0)
        throw new Exception("Optimistic Concurrency Failure");

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); // LINE B: Simulate some data processing

    await using var anotherCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE...", connection, transaction);
    await anotherCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    
    await transaction.CommitAsync(); // LINE C
}
```

The [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) says:

> UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, and SELECT FOR SHARE commands behave the same as SELECT in terms of searching for target rows: they will only find target rows that were committed as of the command start time. However, such a target row might have already been updated (or deleted or locked) by another concurrent transaction by the time it is found. In this case, the would-be updater will wait for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is still in progress).
>
> If the first updater rolls back, then its effects are negated and the second updater can proceed with updating the originally found row. If the first updater commits, the second updater will ignore the row if the first updater deleted it, otherwise it will attempt to apply its operation to the updated version of the row.
>
> The search condition of the command (the WHERE clause) is re-evaluated to see if the updated version of the row still matches the search condition. If so, the second updater proceeds with its operation using the updated version of the row.

How does the above translate to my C# code? Let's assume, I have two requests from two different threads coming in. The first calls

```
await UpdateModelState(connectionString, 42, 5, "Hello One");
```

and the second calls

```
await UpdateModelState(connectionString, 42, 5, "Hello Two");
```

Furthermore, let's assume that request one has already executed LINE A (see comment in source code) and is now busy in LINE B without having committed the transaction, yet.

Will request two then in any case block at LINE A until request one has reached LINE C and committed the transaction?
Or will request two continue to LINE C and the blocking will happen behind the scenes in SQL code only when the second transaction is committed?

I guess and hope it's the former, because if it was the latter, the optimistic concurrency code in C# would be useless, because the `numAffectedRows` would be stale by the time the concurrency is resolved.

In a nutshell, the question is: When does the "search condition of the command (the WHERE clause) is re-evaluated" from the quote above take place for request two on a C# application layer? Does it happen for request two in LINE A or in LINE C?